# Variable not posted on keyup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The input's value should go to PHP for validation dynamically on every keystroke. JS:

```
    $("#coupon-code").on('keyup', function () {
            var coupon = $("#coupon-code").val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"C:/xampp/htdocs/lessdoing/lessdoinglive.com/checkout/page-2/full-pay/coupons/coupons.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {coupon: coupon}
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (data === "success") {
                    $('#coupon-code').css("background-color", "green");
                }
                else {
                    $('#coupon-code').css("background-color", "red");
                }
            })
        });
```

PHP:

```
$coupons = array("foobar", "coupon");

foreach($coupons as $coupon) {
    if ($_POST["coupon"] === $coupon) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo 'invalid';
    }
}
```

I don't see the script echoing out anything in the console. The variable insn't posted.

Comment: You need to post to a url that actually runs a web-server and processes the php. Something that starts with `http`...

Comment: It's still not working. Sorry I had to mod my url after your comment.

Comment: i think your url should be "http:/ /localhost/lessdoing....." if you are running xampp apache

Comment: i think you need to change your url there to at least `http://localhost/lessdoing ... ` etc (remember, url means `Uniform Resource Locator, internet address` meaning you have to use an internet adress). Make sure you check if the call is being made to the file as well. If you have chrome, you can check that by going to the resources, and see if the file is called or that it cant find it.

Comment: I changed the path to a relative one and now XHR are going through. It's still not validating however.

Answer (score 3):

## 1. The URL

```
url:"C:/xampp/htdocs/lessdoing/lessdoinglive.com/checkout/page-2/full-pay/coupons/coupons.php"
```

its not really an URL that is processed by your web server. File is opened from filesystem by your browser and does nothing, as its not pushed via php preprocessor. It must be an proper URI, let say, if you can visit you site with `http://127.0.0.1/lessdoing/checkout/page-2/full-pay/coupons/coupons.php`, your URL should be `/lessdoing/checkout/page-2/full-pay/coupons/coupons.php`. Full representation should work too, but is not necessary.

## 2. There will be no echo in console

as of PHP part of script is running on server-side, there will be no echo in browser console. To `echo` anything in your browser you will have to implement that in your `.done()` callback in your JS, eg:

```
.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data === "success") {
        $('#coupon-code').css("background-color", "green");
    }
    else {
        $('#coupon-code').css("background-color", "red");
    }
})
```

## 3. Posting POST

Your JS script is not currently sending form format that PHP recognises and pust to `$_POST` array. This fix is quick, you need `dataType: 'html'`.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/lessdoing/lessdoinglive.com/checkout/page-2/full-pay/coupons/coupons.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {coupon: coupon}
})
```

## 4. PHP upgrade

```
if(in_array($_POST["coupon"], $coupons)) echo "success";
else echo "invalid";
```

As in other answer, hardly, but **MAY** be a situation, when you put coupon twice in your `$coupons` array and produce "successsuccess" instead of "success".

Comment: I changed the path to a relative one and now the requests result in 200. Yet it's still not validating. Do you see anything wrong with the PHP script?

Comment: Not working still for some reason. The field doesn't turn green. Changed to `in_array` function and now it's working.

Comment: @StevensHaen if you found my answer solving your problem, please accept it by clicking "check" mark on left side of it. It will mark question answered to not remain in search results for those questions whose not yet solved.

Answer (score 2):

```
url:"C:/xampp/htdocs/lessdoing/lessdoinglive.com/checkout/page-2/full-pay/coupons/coupons.php",
```

This line must be url. You wrote server file path.

```
.done(function (data) {
alert(data);
                if (data === "success") {
                    $('#coupon-code').css("background-color", "green");
                }
                else {
                    $('#coupon-code').css("background-color", "red");
                }
            })
```

If you add alert function, you can see data variable value.

```
$coupons = array("foobar", "coupon");

foreach($coupons as $coupon) {
    if ($_POST["coupon"] === $coupon) {
        echo "success";
break;
    } else {
        echo 'invalid';
    }
}
```

And
If you add break in success area, performance upgraded. Or you can use in_array function.

```
$coupons = array("foobar", "coupon");

if (in_array($_POST["coupon"], $coupons)) {
   echo "success";
} else {
   echo "invalid";
}
```